# Increase stack size

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi, stack-size

I'm doing computations with huge arrays and for some of this computations I need an increased stack size! Is there any downside of setting the stack size to unlimited (`ulimit -s unlimited`) in my ~/.bashrc?

The program is written in fortran(F77 & F90) and parallelized with MPI. Some of my arrays have more than 2E7 entries and when I use a small number of cores with MPI it crashes with `segmentation fault`.

The array size stays the same through the whole computation therefore I setted them to fixes value:

```
real         ::  p(200,200,400)
integer      ::  ib,ie,jb,je,kb,ke 
...
ib=1;ie=199
jb=2;je=198
kb=2;ke=398
call  SOLVE_POI_EQ(rank,p(ib:ie,jb:je,kb:ke),R)
```

Comment: What kind of software are you running? In which programming language? Are you coding it? Could you show some source code (so **edit your question** to improve it)?

Comment: Fortran77, Fortran90, Fortran2006? Show the actual code dealing (and allocating) your huge arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the stacksize to unlimited likely won't help you. You are allocating a chunk of 64MB on the stack, and likely don't fill it from the top, but from the bottom.

This is important, because the OS grows the stack as you go. Whenever it detects a page-fault right below the stack segment, it will assume that you need more space, and silently insert a new page. The size of this trigger-region within your address-space is limited, though, and I doubt that its larger than 64 MB. Since you index variables are likely placed below your array on the stack, accessing them already does the 64 MB jump that kills your process.

Just make your array `allocatable`, add the corresponding `allocate()` statement, and you should be fine.

Comment: I always thought that `allocatable` arrays are used when the size of an array changes during runtime? Mine are fixed from the beginning and the stay the  same size during the whole computation!

Comment: You can use `allocatable` to create arrays with dynamic size, but it is also useful to avoid large stack allocations. An allocatable array is always allocated on the heap which does not have the limitations of the stack. And the `allocate()` statement won't complain if you pass it a compile time constant ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Stack size is never really unlimited, so you would still have some failures. And your code still won't be portable to Linux systems with smaller (or normal-sized) stacks.

BTW, you should explain which kind of programs are you running, show some source code.

If coding in C++, using standard [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) should help a lot (regarding actual stack consumption). For example, a local (stack allocated) `std::vector<int> v(10000);` (instead of `int v[10000];`) has its data allocated on the heap (and deallocated by the destructor when you exit from the block defining it)

It would be much better to improve your programs to avoid excessive stack consumption. The need of a lot of stack space is really a bug that you should try to correct. A typical rule of thumb is to have [call frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#CALL-FRAME) smaller than a few kilobytes (so allocate any larger data on the heap).

You might consider also using the [Boehm conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/): you would use `GC_MALLOC` instead of `malloc` (and you would heap allocate large data structure using `GC_MALLOC`) but you won't have to bother to `free` your (GC-heap allcoated) data.

Comment: I edited my question! The most importat thing for my code is to reduce the computational time. The arrays always stay the same size therefore I setted it to a fixed value!

Comment: Allocating the arrays in the heap should not change much the CPU time.

Comment: Ok but i don't see the advantage if I set it to an fixed value when I create them. Or is `p(ib:ie,jb:je,kb:ke)` the problem?

Comment: Might be a problem as the compiler night create a temporary array on the stack (please consult the documentation of the compiler to see if there are possibilities to place the arrays in the heap).